# A problem in Fourier transformation of Coulomb potential

Tags: electrostatics, fourier-transform

Firstly, we calculate the Fourier transformation of $1/|\mathbf{k}|^{2}$
as follows,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\frac{d^{3}k}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{k}|^{2}}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} & = & \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}(2\pi)\int_{0}^{\infty}d|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{k}|^{2}\int_{-1}^{1}dy\frac{1}{|\mathbf{k}|^{2}}e^{i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|y}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}d|\mathbf{k}|\frac{1}{i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|}\bigg(e^{i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|}-e^{-i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|}\bigg)\\
 & = & \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}d|\mathbf{k}|\frac{1}{i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|}2i\mathrm{sin}(|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|)\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2\pi^{2}|\mathbf{x}|}\int_{0}^{\infty}d|\mathbf{k}|\frac{\mathrm{sin}(|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|)}{|\mathbf{k}|}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2\pi^{2}|\mathbf{x}|}\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{\mathrm{sin}x}{x}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2\pi^{2}|\mathbf{x}|}\times\frac{\pi}{2}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{4\pi|\mathbf{x}|}
\end{eqnarray*}

i.e.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int\frac{d^{3}k}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{|\mathbf{k}|^{2}}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} & = & \frac{1}{4\pi|\mathbf{x}|}
\end{eqnarray*}

Obviously, we expect that the inverse transformation is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int d^{3}x\frac{1}{4\pi|\mathbf{x}|}e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} & = & \frac{1}{|\mathbf{k}|^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}

But when we explicitly calculate this inverse transformation, we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int d^{3}x\frac{1}{4\pi|\mathbf{x}|}e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}} & = & \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}d|\mathbf{x}||\mathbf{x}|^{2}\int_{-1}^{1}dy\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|}e^{-i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|y}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}d|\mathbf{x}||\mathbf{x}|\frac{1}{-i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|}(e^{-i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|}-e^{i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|})\\
 & = & \frac{i}{2k}\int_{0}^{\infty}d|\mathbf{x}|(e^{-i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|}-e^{i|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|})\\
 & = & \frac{i}{2|\mathbf{k}|}\int_{0}^{\infty}d|\mathbf{x}|(-2i)\mathrm{sin}(|\mathbf{k}||\mathbf{x}|)\\
 & = & \frac{1}{|\mathbf{k}|^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\mathrm{sin}x\\
 & \neq & \frac{1}{|\mathbf{k}|^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}

So what is wrong with this inverse transformation?

Comment: These problems are related to the fact that the Coulomb potential doesn't vanish sufficiently quickly as $\mathbf{x}\rightarrow \infty$.  This leads to strange things like non-convergent integrals like $\int_0^\infty dx\,\sin(x)$ as you see.  Try repeating the exercise with the screened Coulomb potential $V(r) = e^{-\mu r}/r$.  You can take the screening off, after performing the necessary Fourier transformations, but not before.

Comment: Yes, the screened Coulomb potential $\frac{1}{r}e^{-mr}$ does work.
Actually, I just want to know why the inverse Fourier transformation
does not exit. Thank you.

Comment: @RenhongFang The inverse FT coincides with the original function if $\hat{f}$ is integrable, which is not the case for $1/x$. To my knowledge this is also the most general condition for $\hat{\hat{f}}=f$ everywhere.